# encoding a PHP variable with quotes and line breaks to be passed to a Javascript function (and then reverse the encoding)

Tags: php

Say you have a PHP variable called $description with the following value (that contains quotes and line breaks):

```
Tromp L'oeil Sheath Dress

You will certainly "trick the eye" of many in this gorgeous illusion. Add it to your fall wardrobe before it disappears.
```

You want to pass the contents of this variable into a Javascript function that writes that value into an INPUT of type text.

How would you do this? I tried this:

```
$description = htmlspecialchars ( $product->description, ENT_QUOTES );
```

However, I get a JS error. I also tried this:

```
$description = rawurlencode ( $product->description );
```

This encodes the value like so:

```
Michael%20Kors%0A%0ATromp%20L%27oeil%20Sheath%20Dress%0A%0AYou%20will%20certainly%20%22trick%20the%20ey%22%20of%20many%20in%20this%20gorgeous%20illusion.%20Add%20it%20to%20your%20fall%20wardrobe%20before%20it%20disappears.%0A%0AAvailable%20in%20Black%2FNude
```

This value can be passed as a JS variable, but I don't know of a JS function that will cleanly reverse a PHP rawurlencode.

Is there a matching pair of functions that I could use to encode a variable in PHP to allow it to be passed into a JS function -- and then reverse the encoding in JS so that I get the original value of the PHP variable?

EDIT: To clarify the question and reply to comments, here is some test code:

```
<?php
$str =<<<EOT
Tromp L'oeil Sheath Dress

You will certainly "trick the eye" of many in this gorgeous illusion. Add it to your fall wardrobe before it disappears.
EOT;
echo 'here is the string: <pre>' . $str . '</pre>';
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
<?php
// this does not work with JS as i get an unterminated string literal if i just use addslashes in the following commented-out line
// echo 'alert(\'' . addslashes($str) . '\');';

// this works with JS (the alert activates) but how do i un-rawurlencode in JS?
// echo 'alert(\'' . rawurlencode($str) . '\');';

// this does not work with JS, because of the line breaks
echo 'alert(\'' . htmlspecialchars ($str, ENT_QUOTES) . '\');';
?>
</script>
```

Comment: Why not just echo the actual variable into a JavaScript variable? All you need to worry about is the single and/or double quotes, which can easily be fixed with `addslashes()`...

Comment: What method are you getting this into js from PHP?  Is it just echoed into script tags assigning js variables and executing somewhere in the post-output html?

Comment: Can you be more specific on what "doesn't work" with htmlspecialchars ?

Comment: Thanks for the fast comments, I added some sample code so you can see my question more clearly...

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168214/pass-a-php-string-to-a-javascript-variable-including-escaping-newlines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into problems using some of the answers proposed here, including issues with line breaks and decoding certain html entitites like /. I ended up using rawurlencode (in PHP) and decodeURIComponent (in Javascript) as matching functions to encode/decode the string so it could be passed as a JS variable. Here is working code for anybody else running into this problem.

```
<?php
$str =<<<EOT
Tromp L'oeil Sheath Dress

You will certainly "trick the eye" of many in this gorgeous illusion. Add it to your fall wardrobe before it disappears.
Available in Black/Nude
EOT;
echo 'here is the string: <pre>' . $str . '</pre>';
?>
<p>below is the variable doc.write'd after being rawurlencod'ed in PHP then decodeURIComponent'ed in JS:</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php
echo 'document.write(decodeURIComponent("'. rawurlencode($str).'"));';
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

simplest would be to use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode) if available. It encodes the string according to the [JSON data format](http://json.org/) that is a subset of JavaScript; so any JSON is also valid JavaScript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php
    echo 'alert('. json_encode($str).');';
?>
</script>
```

Otherwise try [PHP’s `rawurlencode`](http://php.net/rawurlencode) and decode it with [JavaScript’s `decodeURI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Functions/decodeURI):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php
    echo 'alert(decodeURI("'. rawurlencode($str).'"));';
?>
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, just to follow up, decodeURI almost works, but doesn't decode certain characters like /, so I went with decodeURIComponent, as you can see in my answer...

Answer (score 0):

Json is the solution. 
See sample code 
Two pages to demonstrate

First Page json.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>


<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    // This is more like it!
    $('#submit').live('click', function() {
        var id=$("#id").attr("value");
        $.getJSON("json-call.php", {id:id}, function callback(data) {
            $("#list").html("var1:"+data['var1']+"<br/>"+"var2:"+data['var2']+"<br />id:"+data['id']);
        });
    });

  });
</script>

<input id="id" type="text" value="test value" />
<input type="button" id="submit" value="submit" />

<div id="list"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

Second Page json-call.php

```
$var1 = 'your name';
$var2 = 'your address';
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
print(json_encode(array ('var1' => $var1, 'var2' => $var2, 'id'=>$id)));
```

and Results

```
var1:your name
var2:your address
id:test value
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether json_decode does everything you need. htmlspecialchars() and htmlspecialchars_decode() should do the trick for everything but the line breaks.  The line breaks are kind of a pain, since the combination of linebreaks and carriage returns will depend on the browser, but I think something like this should work:

```
$value = "your string with quotes and newlines in it.";

//take cares of quotes
$js_value = htmlspecialchars($value);    
//first line replaces an ASCII newline with a JavaScript newline
$js_value = str_replace("\n",'\n',$js_value);
//second line replaces an ASCII carriage return with nothing, so you don't get duplicates
$js_value = str_replace("\r",'',$js_value);

//reverse to convert it back to PHP
$php_value = str_replace('\n',"\r\n",$js_value);  
$php_value = htmlspecialchars_decode($php_value);
```

Maybe not the most elegant solution, but that's not really my specialty. ;)  Also, keep in mind that newline characters will just end up like spaces in an <input type="text"> field.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a litle something I have made:

```
function safefor_js($str) {
    return str_replace(array("'",'"',"\n"), array('\x22','\x27','\\n'), $str);
}
```

Comment: What about the backslash character?

Comment: I didn't think of that, but I don't think it is needed. I just tested it with things like: "a\na", "a\x22a", "a\xn\x22a", "a\x27a" (all with out the quotes) and it did not break the page in any way. Is there something I'm missing? If I'm wrong I definitely would want to fix it.